# How to upgrade openSSH version in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: package-management, openssh

I need to upgrade the openSSH version present in my ubuntu server to a higher version.

Please provide me steps to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The higher version you can get in lucid is `1:5.3p1-3ubuntu7`. That's the only one. If you need higher you may upgrade your server to 12.04 instead otherwise I see difficult upgrading the package.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid-updates/openssh-server

Comment: Thnxs for the inputs.But I am new to Ubuntu and openSSH. would be much helpful if yuou can provide the manual steps

Comment: @adarshmohapatra the manual steps are **upgrade your Ubuntu**, this is easy as cake https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html